# Karma runner testing ASP.NET MVC application with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a ASP.MVC application that is using Windows authentication mode. I have set up Karma test runner and created some end-to-end unit tests to test the app.

Karma starts Chrome browser, navigates to my page and I get `HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized`. However I can access the app if I open it in new tab (of the same Chrome window).

Is there a way how authorize the test runner proxy to access the site? Also how can I get over the authentication popup in case it appears?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by adding a HTTP proxy (in addition to Karma) that would perform the authentication. I used Fiddler because it's primarly intended as a HTTP debugger, which was a nice match for a development environment.

First, Fiddler must be configured as a reverse proxy, as described in http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy

(if you follow my sample code below, the value for  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2\ReverseProxyForPort will be 803, which is the port I used for IIS)

Then, in Fiddler, create a Custom Rule (Rules > Customize Rules...) to add a hardcoded username/password to the request:

In "static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)", add:

```
// Authentication for automated test

if ((oSession.host.Equals("localhost:8888"))) { // Fiddler listening on port 8888

// Redirect to IIS on port 803
oSession.host = "localhost:803";

// Specify username and password for Windows authentication
// WARNING: This should be used only in a development environment and with a user
// account that has limited rights in the domain
oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "DOMAIN\\user:password";

// TODO: oSession could also be inspected for "test" 
// parameters that would use a different user (with different rights) for different test cases
```

And, in your Karma configuration file (example where only "/app/ and /api" are redirected to IIS):

```
  conf.proxies = {  
    // port 8888 = Fiddler proxy with redirection to localhost:803 and auto-Windows authentication 
    '/app/': 'http://localhost:8888/app/', 
    '/api/': 'http://localhost:8888/api/'
  };
```